# Ripped Paper CSS Effect using Polygon

Tags: css, clip-path

I am trying to generate a box with ripped paper effect.So far I have tried and have found only this link to code pen which achieves partially what I am trying to do: https://codepen.io/dsm-webdsigner/pen/dYBRYw

What is missing is I need to achieve that paper effect on the all 4 sides of the paper. As far as I understand, it is achieved using clip-path proper and polygon() function of CSS.

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 5%  100%, 10% 0%, 15%  100%, 20% 0%, 25% 100%, 30% 0%, 35%  100%, 40% 0%, 45%  100%, 50% 0%, 55%  100%, 60% 0%, 65%  100%, 70% 0%, 75%  100%, 80% 0%, 85%  100%, 90% 0%, 95%  100%, 100% 0%,0% 0%, 5%  100%, 10% 0%, 15%  100%, 20% 0%, 25% 100%, 30% 0%, 35%  100%, 40% 0%, 45%  100%, 50% 0%, 55%  100%, 60% 0%, 65%  100%, 70% 0%, 75%  100%, 80% 0%, 85%  100%, 90% 0%, 95%  100%, 100% 0%,0% 0%, 5%  100%, 10% 0%, 15%  100%, 20% 0%, 25% 100%, 30% 0%, 35%  100%, 40% 0%, 45%  100%, 50% 0%, 55%  100%, 60% 0%, 65%  100%, 70% 0%, 75%  100%, 80% 0%, 85%  100%, 90% 0%, 95%  100%, 100% 0%);
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to achieve those effect on all 4 sides? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To generate  a clip-path of your choice you can use this site https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's only top and bottom because in that example there are only 2 elements used `before` and `after` on the `.content-box`. You need another 2 elements to have left and right 'ripple' effect.

For that, you can add `before` and `after` to the parent `.content-main`. Use the same `clip-path` so it saves you the trouble but position them differently so the effect looks nice.

It's not the final version, you can add one more wrapper for overflow hidden or you can erase the rotate and position them differently ( but then you have to change the polygon coordonates and i don't think you want that ). But i think it's a very good start for you.

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #333;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
  line-height: 25px;
}

.content-main {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.content-main:before, .content-main:after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 5% 100%, 10% 0%, 15% 100%, 20% 0%, 25% 100%, 30% 0%, 35% 100%, 40% 0%, 45% 100%, 50% 0%, 55% 100%, 60% 0%, 65% 100%, 70% 0%, 75% 100%, 80% 0%, 85% 100%, 90% 0%, 95% 100%, 100% 0%);
}
.content-main:before {
  background-color: #eee;
  left: -50%;
}
.content-main:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  right: -50%;
}
.content-main .content-box {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.content-main .content-box:before, .content-main .content-box:after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 5% 100%, 10% 0%, 15% 100%, 20% 0%, 25% 100%, 30% 0%, 35% 100%, 40% 0%, 45% 100%, 50% 0%, 55% 100%, 60% 0%, 65% 100%, 70% 0%, 75% 100%, 80% 0%, 85% 100%, 90% 0%, 95% 100%, 100% 0%);
}
.content-main .content-box:before {
  background-color: #eee;
  top: 0;
}
.content-main .content-box:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-main">
  <div class="content-box">
    <h2>Ripped Paper Effect</h2>
    <p>Enthusiastically leverage other's effective users via client-centric portals. Energistically promote principle-centered portals vis-a-vis virtual strategic theme areas. Assertively streamline premium alignments through focused total linkage.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, looks like one or more of your polygon points if off, since it causes excess shape at the top right.

Answer (score 2):

What about using some background and `radial-gradient` to have as similar effect:

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #333;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
  line-height: 25px;
}

.content-main {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.content-main .content-box {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  background: 
  radial-gradient(circle at bottom, #fff 85%,transparent 0%)top /20px 20px repeat-x,
  radial-gradient(circle at top, #fff 85%,transparent 0%)bottom /20px 20px repeat-x,
  radial-gradient(circle at left, #fff 85%,transparent 0%)right /20px 20px repeat-y,
  radial-gradient(circle at right, #fff 85%,transparent 0%)left /20px 20px repeat-y,
  linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) center/calc(100% - 40px) calc(100% - 40px) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-main">
  <div class="content-box">
    <h2>Ripped Paper Effect</h2>
    <p>Enthusiastically leverage other's effective users via client-centric portals. Energistically promote principle-centered portals vis-a-vis virtual strategic theme areas. Assertively streamline premium alignments through focused total linkage.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As other mentioned they're using the same clip path on the pseudo-elements on that div, however we can get rid of those and have our clip-path that clips the div it self.

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #333;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
  line-height: 25px;
}

.content-main {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.content-main .content-box {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 5% 2%, 10% 0%, 15% 2%, 20% 0%, 25% 2%, 30% 0%, 35% 2%, 40% 0%, 45% 2%, 50% 0%, 55% 2%, 60% 0%, 65% 2%, 70% 0%, 75% 2%, 80% 0%, 85% 2%, 90% 0%, 95% 2%, 100% 0%, 98% 5%, 100% 10%, 98% 15%, 100% 20%, 98% 25%, 100% 30%, 98% 35%, 100% 40%, 98% 45%, 100% 50%, 98% 55%, 100% 60%, 98% 65%, 100% 70%, 98% 75%, 100% 80%, 98% 85%, 100% 90%, 98% 95%, 100% 100%, 95% 98%, 90% 100%, 85% 98%, 80% 100%, 75% 98%, 70% 100%, 65% 98%, 60% 100%, 55% 98%, 50% 100%, 45% 98%, 40% 100%, 35% 98%, 30% 100%, 25% 98%, 20% 100%, 15% 98%, 10% 100%, 5% 98%, 0% 100%, 2% 95%, 0% 90%, 2% 85%, 0% 80%, 2% 75%, 0% 70%, 2% 65%, 0% 60%, 2% 55%, 0% 50%, 2% 45%, 0% 40%, 2% 35%, 0% 30%, 2% 25%, 0% 20%, 2% 15%, 0% 10%, 2% 5%);
}
```

```html
<div class="content-main">
  <div class="content-box">
    <h2>Ripped Paper Effect</h2>
    <p>Enthusiastically leverage other's effective users via client-centric portals. Energistically promote principle-centered portals vis-a-vis virtual strategic theme areas. Assertively streamline premium alignments through focused total linkage.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```